# What is wrong with my code? Iterating through a 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following program:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StreetPeople {
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int houses;
        int houseNumbers[];
        int count;
        int houseAges[][] = new int[4][];
        int age;
        int people;

        System.out.print("How many houses on the street? : ");
        houses = keyboard.nextInt();
        houseNumbers = new int[houses];

        for (count = 0; count < houses; count++) {
            System.out.print("What is the next house number? : ");
            houseNumbers[count] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        for (count = 0; count < houseNumbers.length; count++) {
            System.out.print("How many people live in number " + houseNumbers[count] + ": ");
            people = keyboard.nextInt();
            houseAges[count] = new int[people];

            for (int i = 0; i < houseAges.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("What is the age of person " + (i+1) + ":");
                age = keyboard.nextInt();
                houseAges = new int[people][age];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the console window output (which I guess got condensed by StackOverflow):

```
How many houses on the street? : 4
What is the next house number? : 1
What is the next house number? : 3
What is the next house number? : 4
What is the next house number? : 6
How many people live in number 1: 5
What is the age of person 1: 32
What is the age of person 2: 28
What is the age of person 3: 12
What is the age of person 4: 8
What is the age of person 5: 5
How many people live in number 3: 1
What is the age of person 1: 84
How many people live in number 4: 5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at StreetPeople.main(StreetPeople.java:31)
```

The code works perfectly fine until there. I’m completely at loss as to why it works for several iterations, but doesn’t work for house number 4.

Comment: explain what is the expected behaviour and why it seems not correct to you.

Comment: I am expecting it to create an irregular array of size x representing how many people live in that house and each element of that array will have the age of each person in the house.

Answer (score 1):

houseAges only has 4 rows.

```
int houseAges[][] = new int[4][];
```

Answer (score 1):

`int houseAges[][] = new int[4][];`  //here is the problem

to fix change to like below

```
  System.out.print("How many houses on the street? : ");
  houses = keyboard.nextInt();
  houseNumbers= new int[houses];
  houseAges = new int[houses][];  //here you need to initialize houseAges
```

Remove the below line from your code

```
 houseAges[count] = new int[people];
```

Comment: I changed it to what you posted and it still does not work. the error seems to be at:                                               houseAges[count] = new int[people];

Comment: @NickD Remove the below line from your code      houseAges[count] = new int[people];

Comment: it worked!!! but why was that segment of code causing the problem?

Comment: It will create new array with people size instead of using original array.

Answer (score 1):

Here, a fixed size. When you call the next number and get error.

```
int houseAges[][] = new int[4][];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem :

```
houseAges = new int[people][age];
```

You reinitialize your `houseAges` array completely

Now since in your third house you chose 1 person then you initialize your array with one person which makes the loop crash on the second index (since now `houseAges` first dimension is of size 1)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < houseAges.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("What is the age of person " + (i+1) + ":");
    age = keyboard.nextInt();
    houseAges = new int[people][age];  // I guess it should be houseAges[people][i] = age; no need to reallocate the entire array on every iteration.
}
```